# Can i convert html code to json data?

Tags: java, android, html, json, image

My question is actually a little bit more complex, I am working on a project which is supposed to download a lot of pictures from a website. I am not sure if the website is providing json data so i can obtain from there the url's of each image.

Is there a possibility to convert html code in json data in order to identify all the image url's?

What would be a best practice in this case ?

Comment: can you provide more information? as like you are doing at this moment.

Comment: the best solution in this case will be look for `<img>` tags using regex

Comment: Please do accept the answer if it solved your problem or post the solution that you have found and accept it. So that it could help others.